# Perl substitution from Python in Anaconda on Windows platform

Tags: python, perl, subprocess

In an Anaconda shell environment on Windows with perl, m2-base and maybe some other packages installed:

```
$ echo "/" > junk
$ more junk
"/"
$ perl -pi.bak -e "s/\"\/\"/\"\\\\\"/" junk
$ more junk junk.bak
::::::::::::::
junk
::::::::::::::
"\"
::::::::::::::
junk.bak
::::::::::::::
"/"
```

I want to replicate this in Python. My script is this:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'perl -pi.bak -e "s/\"\/\"/\"\\\\\"/" junk'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell = True)
```

which gives the following output:

```
$python test_perl.py
Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.
```

I have tried different combinations of backslashes, different quotation styles, and using a different delimiter in perl (i.e. replacing the `/` with something like `@`), but can't seem to figure out how to crack this nut.

**UPDATE**

`subprocess.call(['perl', '-pi.bak', '-e', "s!\\\"\/\"!\"\\\\\\\"!", 'junk'], shell = True)` works, but I'm confused about why `subprocess` does not need extra quotes to encapsulate the perl switch statement. Any insights would be appreciated.

--

For more info on what I'm actually doing, I am trying to install a Python module that was designed for Linux/Unix on my Windows platform in an Anaconda environment. For one part, I need to replace "/" with "\" in some of the files of the module. I am aware that I could edit the files directly and use something like `os.path.split` instead of just `split("/")` but I am trying to create a file that does all the work, so all one needs to do is clone the git repository and run a setup script.

Comment: From your code it looks like in a file you try to replace `"/"` with `"\"`. You refer to Unix/Linux for written python module, which you try to use in Windows. Well it sounds like you try to replace _directory/file divider_ in a path strings. If it is so then path does not includes `"` around each _directory/file divider_. Perhaps you need to describe your problem in a way which will uncover the problem in more clear way.

Comment: It is somewhat strange to call for Perl from Python script to do such simple substitution. Why do not use power of Python to make such change without assistance of the Perl?

Comment: Perl is not integral part of Windows. Are you suggesting that to clone your git repository the user has to install Perl to be able utilize the module?

Comment: @Polar Bear - good questions. The Python module is messy, wraps a whole bunch of f90 code from different sources, and uses a whole bunch of nested Makefiles download files and alter the contents before compiling. This is all before building the module itself. I wanted to make sure that what I wrote followed the Makefiles clearly, so rather than rewriting the Makefiles in native Python, I rebuilt them with `subprocess` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following python demo code emulate `perl -i.bak ...` behavour.

Problem description does not explains why OP resorts to Perl assistance to make simple substitution with preserving `.bak` file as backup copy.

Python has enough *muscle* to perform such operation, just a few lines of code.

```
import os

ext_bak  = '.bak'
file_in  = 'path_substitute.txt'
file_bak = file_in + ext_bak

# remove backup file if exists
if os.path.exists(file_bak):
    os.remove(file_bak)

# rename original file to backup
os.rename(file_in,file_bak);

f = open(file_bak,'r')  # read from backup file
o = open(file_in, 'w')  # write to a file with original name

for line in f:
    o.write(line.replace('/','\\'))    # replace / with \ and write

# close files
f.close()
o.close()
```

Input `path_substitute.txt`

```
some path /opt/pkg/dir_1/file_1 word_1
other path /opt/pkg/dir_2/file_2 word_2
one more /opt/pkg/dir_3/file_3 word_3
```

Output `path_substitute.txt`

```
some path \opt\pkg\dir_1\file_1 word_1
other path \opt\pkg\dir_2\file_2 word_2
one more \opt\pkg\dir_3\file_3 word_3
```

Comment: Agreed, that Python has the *muscle*, as you say, and I agree that you don't need to use Perl. I was more wondering why the `subprocess` call wasn't doing what I expected, rather than figuring out how to make the switch, so that's on me for not explaining properly.